# Plugin Cordova PayPal em Ionic utilizando Real (BRL)

Tags: angular, ionic3, cordova-plugin, pagamento-online

Instalei o plugin do PayPal em uma aplicação Ionic seguindo esse tutorial: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/paypal/

Criei uma conta SandBox, marquei que a conta é no "Brazil".
A aplicação funciona perfeitamente se eu enviar, na api, a moeda "USD". 
Mas se eu disser que a moeda é "BRL" diz que o PayPal não trabalha com essa moeda, como ilustram as imagens abaixo:

[image: Mensagem]

Como mostra a mensagem, pensei que BRL não era uma moeda válida, mas achei uma página no paypal que diz que BRL é aceito apenas para "in-country PayPal accounts only".

Afinal, o que isso quer dizer? A minha conta no PayPal foi criada selecioando BRAZIL e a transação é realizada em um app no Brasil, passando BRL como moeda.

Alguém conseguiu implementar PayPal em Ionic/Cordova/Angular?

Comment: Cara vc leu a documrntaçao... Se me lembro bem brl esta depreciado

Comment: Não achei nada na documentação que elucidasse esse ponto...